# Binding a JavaFX variable to a Java variable/object

Tags: java, data-binding, binding, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX application that contains a Java Swing GUI panel (it's the [OpenBlocks](http://education.mit.edu) workspace to be specific).

I want to detect certain events that occur in the Java Swing panel from the JavaFX side and respond to them.  I have an event listener in the JavaFX environment, and when that listener "hears" an event, I want to make some JavaFX GUI object visible, so I was thinking of trying to bind the "visible" property of these objects to some variable Java variable that will update when the events of interest occur; but I tried to do this binding, and it is not working for me.

So my general question is: Is there a way to bind a JavaFX variable to a Java variable/object, and if so, how is this done?

Thank you in advance for any help on this!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX 2.0 you can do this the `javafx.beans.binding.ObjectProperty<T>` (and related) classes.